# Split a Range of Numbers into different Rows - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe having column values like this:

```
 num_range      id      description
'5000-6000'      1        lmn
'6100-6102'      1        lmn
'6363-6363'      3        xyz
'Q7890-Q8000'    2        pqr
```

So is there a way I can write a loop which will split into rows and give me the values, for ex. for the first `num_range` value, something like this:

```
num_range      id      description
   5000          1        lmn
   5001          1        lmn
   5002          1        lmn
   .....        ...       ....
   5999          1        lmn 
   6000          1        lmn
   Q7891         2        pqr
   Q7892         2        pqr
   ...          ...       ...
   Q8000         2        pqr
```

Like wise I want rows for all the `num_range` values along with the `id` and the `description`.

Comment: for loops, df.iterrows and df.append will get you there

Comment: i was trying with for loop and groupby id but didn't work for me or maybe I'm going somewhere wrong, I'm not able to figure out

Comment: not sure groupby will help as your keys aren't very consistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for get numeric values, also working if before non numeric values like `F` in last row, then create Series by lists comprehension and `join` to original:

```
print (df)
     num_range  id description
0    5000-5005   1         lmn
1    6100-6102   1         lmn
2    6363-6363   3         xyz
3  Q7890-Q7893   2         pqr


s = df.pop('num_range').str.findall('\d+')
a = [(i, x) for i, (a, b) in s.items() for x in range(int(a), int(b) + 1)]
s = pd.DataFrame(a).set_index(0)[1].rename('num_range')

df = df.join(s)
print (df)
   id description  num_range
0   1         lmn       5000
0   1         lmn       5001
0   1         lmn       5002
0   1         lmn       5003
0   1         lmn       5004
0   1         lmn       5005
1   1         lmn       6100
1   1         lmn       6101
1   1         lmn       6102
2   3         xyz       6363
3   2         pqr       7890
3   2         pqr       7891
3   2         pqr       7892
3   2         pqr       7893
```

If need also first value before numeric first extract this values by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), replace `-` toe emty string and map in list comprehension:

```
d = df['num_range'].str.extract('(\D+)\d+', expand=False).replace('-','').to_dict()
print (d)
{0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: 'Q'}

s = df.pop('num_range').str.findall('\d+')
a = [(i, '{}{}'.format(d.get(i), x)) 
      for i, (a, b) in s.items() for x in range(int(a), int(b) + 1)]
s = pd.DataFrame(a).set_index(0)[1].rename('num_range')

df = df.join(s).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    id description num_range
0    1         lmn      5000
1    1         lmn      5001
2    1         lmn      5002
3    1         lmn      5003
4    1         lmn      5004
5    1         lmn      5005
6    1         lmn      6100
7    1         lmn      6101
8    1         lmn      6102
9    3         xyz      6363
10   2         pqr     Q7890
11   2         pqr     Q7891
12   2         pqr     Q7892
13   2         pqr     Q7893
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit brute force but explains a way of explicitly doing it.
One can use `.apply` etc. in fancy ways too to cut out some loops

```
# going to save it here
newdf = pd.DataFrame()

for _, row in df.iterrows():
   # split num_range and cast to a list of ints
   s, e = [x for x in map(int, row.num_range.split("-"))]

   # need to add one to e cause we need to include it
   for n in range(s, e+1):
       # replace the number on the row you've iterated on.
       row.num_range = n
       newdf = newdf.append(row)
```